# Integrating by exhibiting a partition

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Is there some reasonable way of showing that $$\int_{a}^b\ c_0+c_1x+...+c_nx^n\ dx = c_0(b-a)+c_1\frac{(b^2-a^2)}{2}+...+c_n\frac{b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}}{n+1}, $$ by finding a partition of $[a,b]$ with lower and upper sums of the integrand over the interval within some given $\epsilon>0$ of the right-hand side? Basically what I've been trying to do is to get some $k(\epsilon)$ expression that gives me a number $k$ of equally spaced points of $[a,b]$ that do the job, but haven't been particularly successful.

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: The idea of induction crossed my mind, but it wasn't clear to me what would I need to do. And also I figured there must have been some way of determining just how many elements I needed in my partition (when equally spaced) as a function of a, b, c_i's, epsilon, n and so on.

Comment: If I were you, I would try for small values of $n$ first, see what happens.

Comment: I mean, I want to show that for a given epsilon I can find some partition, or maybe that U-I-R_1-...-R_n<epsilon for some n, where U is the upper sum of the partition {a,b}, I is the integral and the R_i's are the rectangles being taken off by taking refinements. How could induction help?

Comment: Are you allowed to use linearity of integration? If so, induction would be very useful.

Comment: Well, I came up with this by myself, so there isn't really any particular requirements on what is allowed or disallowed. I'd just like to stay as close to the definition as possible (whatever that means). But yeah, I think kind of see where you are getting. I'll think some more about it, thanks. I still would like some way of finding that k, so other tips or suggestions are welcome.